# R code to use last column to align all rows length

Tags: r, dataframe, alignment, multiple-columns, rows

I have a pretty complex and large dataframe that I need to do data arranging in R. I can't come up with any possible method to use in R, so any help will be appreciated.

As an example in my dataframe looks something like this:

the raw data

[image]

Now the data has to be finished like this. I'd like to move all the rows by using the column'v8' to align

need to be done like this

[image]

For the NA, there're some NA in the raw data and they are all belong to the specific variables. 
They can just be regarded as values.

Can anyone help please? 
That would be great appreciation !!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  v1=c(12,NA,22,NA),
  v2=c(34,45,88,75),
  v3=c(56,78,78,NA),
  v4=c(78,NA,NA,44),
  v5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
  v6=c(NA,43,67,6),
  v7=c(NA,52,32,NA),
  v8=c(98,NA,NA,NA))


cols <- ncol(df)

df %>%
  unite("id") %>%
  mutate(id2 = gsub("(_NA)*$", "", id)) %>%
  mutate(del_count = cols - 1 - str_count(id2, "_")) %>%
  transmute(col = paste0(strrep("_", del_count), id2)) %>%
  separate(col, paste0("V", 1:cols), "_")

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1 12 34 56 78 NA NA NA 98
2    NA 45 78 NA NA 43 52
3    22 88 78 NA NA 67 32
4       NA 75 NA 44 NA  6
```

It creates concatenated string for all variables then remove the last repeated `NA`s then pad with `'_'` separator which is then used to split the column.

Comment: This not only converts numbers to strings (reversible), but it also no longer differentiates between `NA` and an empty string. It is generally best not to convert back and forth from number to string (and perhaps back to number, you don't do this) when it is not specified, as there can easily be loss (these are ints, so unlikely to lose anything, but still really inefficient).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - totally understand.

Comment: Pretty appreciated~~ I just use separate and unite functions to arrange my data. Now I can just put these functions all together !!

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, that shouldn't be a `data.frame`, that should be a `matrix`: in frames, each column indicates something meaningful and potentially distinct from the neighboring columns; in this picture of data, the *absolute* column in which an integer appears does not appear to hold much meaning, even if the relative position (within a row) does. I suggest you convert to a matrix and stop thinking about this as a frame.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  v1=c(12,NA,22),
  v2=c(34,45,88),
  v3=c(56,78,78),
  v4=c(78,NA,NA),
  v5=c(NA,NA,NA_real_),
  v6=c(NA,43,67),
  v7=c(NA,52,32),
  v8=c(98,NA,NA))

mtx <- as.matrix(df)
t(apply(mtx, 1, function(r) {
  tailna <- rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(r))) == 0L)
  c(r[tailna], r[!tailna])
}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]   12   34   56   78   NA   NA   NA   98
# [2,]   NA   NA   45   78   NA   NA   43   52
# [3,]   NA   22   88   78   NA   NA   67   32
```

If you absolutely must have this as a frame, though, just do this much and then convert it back.

Comment: Thanks, @IceCreamToucan

Comment: Thank you pretty much!! It's worked when I convert to matrix. But when I'd like to convert the matrix back into data frame, the data frame is still looked like the original.

Comment: Did you save the output from `t(apply(...))` back into something? R generally does not operate by *side-effect* (other than, say, the `data.table` package), so you need to store the output from functions into a variable (same or new). Try `mtx <- t(apply(...))` and then `newdf <- as.data.frame(mtx)`.

Comment: Cheers !! Finally work!! yes, I just forgot to output the function!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a quick and dirty loop to achieve this (but this might be inefficient depending on the size of your dataset).

The first level of the loop goes over every row, and checks if the final column contains an NA value - if so, slide everything over by one. Repeat this operation many times in case there are many columns with NA at the end of the dataset and it needs to slide over a long way (using the second level of the loop iterate once for every column in the dataset; n-1 iterations are sufficint).

```
# Dataset
dat <- data.frame(v1 = c(12, NA, 22, NA, NA),
           v3 = c(56, 78, 78, NA, 4),
           v7 = c(NA, 52, 32, NA, 9),
           v8 = c(98, NA, NA, NA, NA))

# Iterate over every row of the dataaset
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
    # Iterate once for every column in the dataset.
    for(j in 1:(length(dat)-1)){
        # if the final column for that row is NA, slide everything over by one.
        if(is.na(dat[i, length(dat)])){
            dat[i,] <- c(NA, dat[i,][-length(dat)])
        }
    }
}
```